# Negate a Q object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-q

I have a complex Q object created dynamically. How do I negate the Q object so that it can be used in `filter()` instead of `exclude()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `~` operator:

```
complex_condition = ~Q(....)
```

According to [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

> `Q` objects can be negated using the **~ operator**, allowing for combined
>   lookups that combine both a normal query and a negated (NOT) query

Comment: @ATOzTOA, `operator.not_(x)` is similar to `not x`. Use `operator.inv(x)` or `oeprator.invert` to mean `~x`. Sorry for late (too late) reply.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.inv

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @falsetru.

What I was trying was running the Q object through another negated Q object:

```
~Q(Q)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant use `~` operator like ~Q(**filters) - use `operator.inv(q)`

```
import operator
negated_q = operator.inv(query)
```

**Usage Example**

```
q_filter = Q(user__profile_id=777)
>> (AND: ('user__profile_id', 777))
```

```
negated_q_filter = operator.inv(q_filter)
>> (NOT (AND: ('user__profile_id', 777)))
```